# Como formatar data por extenso?

Tags: java, data

Existe alguma classe em Java que trabalhe com formatação de data por extenso?

**Por exemplo:**

Entrada: [dd/mm/yyyy]
27/02/2016

Saída: Vinte e sete de Fevereiro de 2016

Tentei:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exemplo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s;

    System.out.printf("Informe o nome da Cidade:\n");
    s = ler.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("\nResultado:\n");
    System.out.printf("%s\n", DataPorExtenso(s, new java.util.Date()));
  }

  public static String NomeDoMes(int i, int tipo) {
    String mes[] = {"janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril",
      "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro",
      "novembro", "dezembro"};
    if (tipo == 0)
       return(mes[i-1]); 
    else return(mes[i-1].substring(0, 3)); 
  }


  public static String DiaDaSemana(int i, int tipo) {
    String diasem[] = {"domingo", "segunda-feira", "terça-feira",
      "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira", "sexta-feira", "sábado"};
    if (tipo == 0)
       return(diasem[i-1]); 
    else return(diasem[i-1].substring(0, 3));
  }

  public static String DataPorExtenso(String cidade, java.util.Date dt) {
    int d = dt.getDate();
    int m = dt.getMonth()+1;
    int a = dt.getYear()+1900;

    Calendar data = new GregorianCalendar(a, m-1, d);
    int ds = data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    return(cidade + ", " + d + " de " + NomeDoMes(m, 0) + " de " +
      a + " (" + DiaDaSemana(ds, 1) + ").");
  }

}
```

A saida foi:

> 27 de Fevereiro de 2016

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para deixar no formato que você quer e com o mês por extenso:

```
Date data =  new Date();
Locale local = new Locale("pt","BR");
DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy",local);
System.out.println(formato.format(data));
```

Isso vai printar, por exemplo, `27 de Fevereiro de 2016`, ou seja, o dia ainda não está por extenso. Não encontrei nada nativo do Java que te devolva os números por extenso da forma que você quer. Mas implementar um método que faça isso também não é muito difícil. Segue a minha versão:

```
public static String getDiaPorExtenso(int dia) throws Exception {
    String dias[] = {"zero", "um", "dois", "três","quatro", "cinco", "seis", "sete", "oito", "nove"};
    String retorno = "";

    if (dia < 1 || dia > 31) {
        throw new Exception("Não existe esse dia em nenhum mês do ano");
    }
    else if (dia < 10) {
        retorno = dias[dia];
    }
    else if (dia < 20) {
        retorno = new String[]{
            "dez", "onze", "doze", "treze", "quatorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezessete", "dezoito", "dezenove"
        }[dia - 10];
    }
    else if (dia < 30) {
        if (dia == 20) {
            retorno = "vinte";
        }
        else {
            retorno = "vinte e " + dias[dia - 20];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (dia == 30) {
            retorno = "trinta";
        }
        else {
            retorno = "trinta e " + dias[dia - 30];
        }
    }

    // Capitaliza apenas a primeira letra do dia.
    return retorno.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + retorno.substring(1);
}
```

Juntando os dois, você pode exibir o resultado final da seguinte forma:

```
Date data = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11).getTime();
Locale local = new Locale("pt","BR");
DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat(" 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", local);
String dataFormatada = formato.format(data);

Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
calendario.setTime(data);
int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

System.out.println(getDiaPorExtenso(dia) + dataFormatada);
```

Saída: `Onze de Fevereiro de 2014`.

**Observação:**

```
Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
calendario.setTime(data);
int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

é utilizado ao invés do mais óbvio `data.getDate()` porque este último método está [**deprecated**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate--).

**Veja o código completo e executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Pi7PXh).**

Comment: Só um adendo: o motivo pelo qual não existe nenhuma API de números por extenso em Java é porque isso é algo extremamente localizado. Cada língua tem suas regras próprias e variações, portanto você acaba tendo que implementar sua rotina.

Comment: Fiz substring para pegar a data e formata-la usando getDiaPorExtenso, seria desta forma ou há outro jeito mais eficiente de pegar o dia ? exemplo funcionando no https://ideone.com/OEpecb

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Inicialmente eu tinha feito dessa sua forma mesmo, mas depois de ler seu comentário pensei num jeito um pouco melhor. Adicionei ele à resposta.

Comment: este DAY_OF_MONTH vai pegar o dia atual, se alguém entrar com uma data antiga acredito que não irá considerar. mas é detalhe.

Comment: Eh, na verdade o que estava me dando apenas o dia atual era o fato de eu não settar uma `Date` na instância do `Calendar`. Consertei de forma que você pode especificar a data que quiser agora (embora no exemplo esteja uma data qualquer, fixa).

Answer (score 2):

A partir do Java 8 é possível usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Uma das diferenças desta API para [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) é que agora [há várias classes diferentes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) para representar datas e horas. No caso, como você está trabalhando apenas com dia, mês e ano, sem se importar com o horário ou *timezones*, pode usar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Para os nomes dos meses, a solução é similar à [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115573/112052): use o formato `MMMM` e o [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) correspondente ao português.

Já para os dias por extenso, não tem muito como fugir de uma solução "manual", que construa o texto um a um. No caso, você pode usar um `Map` que mapeia o valor numérico para o seu respectivo texto, e passá-lo para um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html). No fim criamos um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), que podemos usar para formatar a data:

```
Map<Long, String> dias = new HashMap<>();
dias.put(1L, "Primeiro");
dias.put(2L, "Dois");
dias.put(3L, "Três");
// ... adicionar os textos até o dia 31
dias.put(31L, "Trinta e um");

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // mapeamento dos dias para o texto por extenso
    .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias)
    // nome do mês e valor numérico do ano
    .appendPattern(" 'de' MMMM 'de' uuuu")
    // usar Locale referente ao português (para o nome do mês)
    .toFormatter(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(2016, 2, 27);
System.out.println(data.format(formatter));
```

Eu uso [`ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) para indicar qual o campo que será mapeado para um texto (no caso, o dia do mês), e uso o `Map` contendo os mapeamentos entre o valor numérico e o respectivo texto.

Para o nome do mês, eu uso `MMMM`, que traz o nome completo, e uso o *locale* referente ao idioma português do Brasil (`pt_BR`), para que o nome do mês fique correto. Se você não especificar um *locale*, será usado o *default* que está configurado na JVM, e não é garantido que sempre seja português (inclusive, este pode ser mudado em *runtime* se alguma aplicação chamar [`Locale.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-), afetando todas as aplicações que estiverem rodando na mesma JVM - ou seja, é uma configuração sobre a qual você não tem controle). Então se você já sabe que a saída deve estar em um idioma específico, use o respectivo *locale* em vez de depender do *default*.

---

A pergunta menciona que a entrada será a **string** "27/02/2016". Se esse for o caso, então primeiro você deve converter essa `String` para `LocalDate`, usando **outro** `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("27/02/2016", parser);
... formatar a data, usando o código anterior
```

Só que o `DateTimeFormatter`, por padrão, aceita alguns valores inválidos, como 31 de abril (e ajusta automaticamente para 30 de abril). Se quiser ser mais restrito e só aceitar datas válidas, use um [`java.time.format.ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Para mais detalhes sobre o `ResolverStyle`, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052).

Repare também que nos códigos acima, usei `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano. Basicamente, `u` e `y` diferem no tratamento de datas antes de Cristo, e embora isso não importe muito para datas atuais, é mais garantido usar `u`, que já funciona para ambos os casos. Veja mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418).

Veja também todos os formatos disponíveis na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), se atentando para o fato de que nem todos funcionam exatamente da mesma maneira que `SimpleDateFormat` (algumas letras novas foram adicionadas, outras significam campos diferentes ou não possuem exatamente o comportamento, etc).

---

#### Java 6 e 7

Para JDK 6 e 7, é possível usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que é um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. As classes e métodos são basicamente os mesmos do Java 8, a diferença é que elas ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ou seja, com exceção do nome do pacote, o código ficaria igual ao exemplo acima).

Como é um *backport*, não é 100% igual: existem algumas diferenças para o `java.time`, listadas [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052).

---

Outra opção para transformar os números nos seus respectivos textos por extenso é usar uma biblioteca para isso, como por exemplo [essa](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/wiki/Numeros-por-extenso-core) - se bem que nesse caso me parece um exagero adicionar uma nova dependência só para isso, já que são apenas 31 opções de texto. Além disso, como as classes desta API são [imutáveis e *thread-safe*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/design.html), você pode criar apenas um único `DateTimeFormatter` estático e reutilizá-lo em toda a aplicação, por exemplo (sem precisar ficar convertendo os textos toda hora).

Answer (score -2):

Poderia ser desta forma: d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy

Comment: O `d` retorna o valor numérico do dia (e não o texto por extenso, como pede a pergunta). Além disso, `MMMM` pode não retornar o nome do mês em português, se o locale *default* configurado na JVM não for português. Leia as outras respostas para entender melhor :-)